# Looking for a way to track a True Download of a file, not just the fact that they clicked on a file link

Tags: asp.net, download

As I understand it, when a link to a file is clicked in the browser, the file is silently downloaded to a temporary directory on the computer. Then the prompt is displayed which shows Open, Save, Cancel... Then if the user clicks Save, they are prompted to save it somewhere, and finally the file is basically transferred to that location when confirmed.

Assuming that is correct, I'm looking for a way to determine if the user actually downloaded the file. So basically determine if they clicked the Save button.

The bit of research that I've done leads me to believe this is not possible, because there is no standardized way of capturing that event, however I could be wrong. And the only possible solution I can come up with is to create an actual client application. Any thoughts on that?

Also, if there are any other off the wall ideas, I'm open to those as well.

And in case it makes a difference, I'm working within an ASP.NET environment.

Comment: The only way I would see this possible is to have your user download an executable and have that executable contact a webservice to specify it has downloaded the file. The exe once executed would open the document with it's default application.

Comment: What do you need this information for (as that might change what an appropriate answer is? (You can, for example, verify if the whole file was sent FROM your server at least, or use javascript on the client-side to determine if the whole file was downloaded, or even get the user to signal in some way that they've downloaded the file)

Comment: `As I understand it, when a link to a file is clicked in the browser, the file is silently downloaded to a temporary directory on the computer.` This is not correct. Each browser is different, but generally a browser will just download the file to a "Downloads" folder, and not ask the user where to save it (i.e. it will just start downloading the file)

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, that's similar to what I was thinking.

RB, The reason why I need this is because I have a need to log who downloads certain files. And if they for instance click the Cancel button, it would not be accurate to say they downloaded it.

And in terms of the way that browsers work, here is what I've observed: IE, Firefox, and Edge all prompt you to save/cancel. And Chrome does not, it just downloads the file as you noted.

Answer (score 0):

How about turning this whole problem around and audit the file that actually being downloaded. You can turn on file/folder auditing and  capture onlyt the success and failures of the IIS process. Then correlate the audit event with the pieces parts in the IIS log to get the particulars of who actually downloaded the file.

Just my $0.02 YMMV

Comment: I would think this would still not work, because like I said...most browsers will actually download the entire file to a temp directory, regardless of whether or not you click Save.

Comment: Nope, using the audit capability, it wouldn't matter what was accessing the file (however in this case to keep the noise down e.g. local access) the audit trigger should be limited to the IIS process. -- using the audit mechanism, you could audit access over a network share, FTP, command line etc. The browser involved would play no part what so ever in the audit.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything on this. Can you provide a link. Also, given that I'm using SharePoint, the file wouldn't be stored on a local file system, so I don't see FTP or Network share monitoring working for this.

Comment: In that case, it gets even easier... Here's a list of events that can be tracked with Auditing is turned on in SharePoint 2013 -- 2010 is pretty much the same but can't find at linke right this seconds. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-audit-log-reports-4293E8D5-4E7D-4201-B8AC-C8E63A100131?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#__toc272842194